# jquery ui of drupal not working

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-7

Version Drupal 7.16

I'm trying to use draggable of jquery in Drupal way :

I have a simple page (with hook_menu) wich call an js and render a simple div with the good class to draggable :

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.testJs = {


    attach : function(context, settings) {
        $('.test-js').draggable();
    });
}
}
})(jQuery);
```

This js is load.
I add library of jquery Drupal :

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui');
```

or

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.draggable');
```

But nothing happen....
When I had an external jquery like :

```
 drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js',   'external')
```

draggable work.
I try to enable jquery update module, but nothing more....

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the hook you are calling isn't called int the right order. template_process_html is where css and js are finalized and rendered to template variables.  Try adding your code in hook_preprocess_html and see if that works.  Otherwise find a hook that is called before template_process_html like hook_init.  If that doesn't work give a more detailed code sample of how you are trying to achieve this.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_process_HOOK/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7